# Numeros Primos não mostra resultados

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando rodar esse código no js, mas ele nao esta mostrando os resultados no terminal, tem algo errado no código?

```js
let maximo = 10;
for (let num = 2; num <= maximo; num++) {
  let primo = true;
  for (let i = 2; i < maximo; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      primo = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (primo) {
    console.log(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: Quando você para o laço mais interno, `primo == false`, daí nunca vai entrar naquele if, pois primeiro o laço será todo executado até o break ou até o fim. Creio que esse if ai deveria estar dentro do laço mais interno. https://jsfiddle.net/jf1gh098/

Comment: Ainda sim acho que isso não é suficiente para validar. Lembre-se: a condição de um número para ser primo é ser divisivel apenas por 1 e por ele mesmo. Nenhum dos laços valida isso. Pela sua lógica, nenhum impar é primo, mas o 9, 15, 21, 27 e etc sao todos impares e não primos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é simples, no segundo for, em algum momento o valor será dividido por ele mesmo, o que sempre fará dar zero, basta trocar o máximo por num

```js
let maximo = 10;
for (let num = 2; num <= maximo; num++) {
  let primo = true;
  for (let i = 2 ; i < num ; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      primo = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (primo) {
    console.log(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: Obg, essa resposta me ajudou